# Create custom style Material UI with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mobx-react-form

When creating custom styling with Material UI + redux-form, the Field element from redux-form does not apply the custom class names. When simply using FieldText from Material UI does. I have commented out the non-functioning line of code below.

The custom styles object is being applied the the react component via a prop named 'classes' that is defined on the prototype.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {createOrder} from '../actions';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  textField: {
    flexBasis: 400,
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});


class Order extends Component {

  renderField(field) {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-simple-start-adornment"
          // className={classNames(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Age"

          {...field.input}
        />

      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <form >
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Field
            name="age"
            label="age"
            component={this.renderField}
          />
          <TextField
            id="outlined-simple-start-adornment"
            className={classNames(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Company Name"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

Order.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};



export default reduxForm({
  form: 'Form'
})(
  connect(null, {createOrder})(withStyles(styles)(Order))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but I just ran into a similar issue and I would like to share how I resolved for people who will run into same issue with Material UI and Redux-form:

1. Pass down the classes as props

```html
<Field
  component={this.renderInput}
  classes={classes}
/>
```

2. props contains classes available

```js
renderInput(props) {
  console.log('console logging render input', props);
  return (
    <InputBase
      placeholder='Search…'
      inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
      classes={{
        root: props.classes.root, //call your className
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `classes` is undefined, you can access `classes` from props.

like this.

```
className={classNames(this.props.classes.margin, this.props.classes.textField)}
```

`TextField` should be like this.

```
<TextField
      id="outlined-simple-start-adornment"
      className={classNames(this.props.classes.margin, this.props.classes.textField)}
      variant="outlined"
      label="Age"
      {...field.input}
    />
```

Comment: I was playing around with that as well -- but received a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" when I define classes in the local scope. Could this need componentDidMount? Or is it something with redux-form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have defined `const { classes } = this.props;` in `render()` but it is not accesible inside `renderField(field){...}` due to its scope.

You can not destructure props for whole component.
Destructuring can only assign **local variables** so you'd need to destructure props in each function. Otherwise there's nothing wrong with having to write `this.props.value.`

So here you have two alternatives

1] pass props to `renderField()`  or again destructure `const { classes } = this.props` inside `renderField()`

2] Directly use `this.props.classes` instead of just `classes` in `renderField()`

Comment: I was playing around with that as well -- but received a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" when I define classes in the local scope. Could this need componentDidMount? Or is it something with redux-form?

Comment: Can you post your code so that I can see where you are getting an error